# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean abi44_0_0...FabricViewStateManager.hasStateWrapper()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, react-native

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean abi44_0_0com.facebook.react.uimanager.FabricViewStateManager.hasStateWrapper()' on a null object reference

This was an error occurred when I was trying to compile my code in Android Device, After adding
<TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={"Write a Task"}>

The expo Go version in my android device is 2.24.1.
My device was Oneplus 6T with version 11.1.2.2

Answer (score 5):

Actually It was an issue from expo go latest update(2.24.1). And I downloaded a previous version apk(2.23.2).That solved me the issue. In Version(2.24.4) it has been solved

Comment: Where are you able to download the older version?

Answer (score 2):

I've downloaded the previous version (2.24.3) with the following link, it solved my issue: https://d1ahtucjixef4r.cloudfront.net/Exponent-2.24.3.apk

(following this github issue from the expo team: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17372)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
As far as I have read, this seems to be a bug that "sometimes just occurs"

What I did now to make it work again was

1. update all dependencies
2. update expo to newest version (in my case 5.4.3)
3. set react-native-gesture-handler back to version 1.7.0
4. Literally uninstalled expo go from my phone and reinstalled it via the appstore

I have the feeling that step 4 would have been enough. I tried it with another phone in the meantime and didn't get the error there. So to yeet the Expo Go app and install it again could be the solution.

Expo is getting on my last nerve.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was fixed with the latest Expo Go update, version 2.24.4